# Redraw Button in Jquery Mobile Form after a load event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Since I have begun using jQuery Mobile 1.1.1 I have had trouble getting a form input button to redraw properly. Below is an example of what I have tried. But it only draws the input field like a text field and not a button.

test1.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Test</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#test").live("pageshow",function(event, ui) {
            $("#ajax").load("test2.php", function() {
                $("#test").find('input,textarea').textinput();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head> 
<body> 

    <div id="test" data-role="page" >
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Test</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <input id="button" type="button" value="Normal" data-theme="b"/>
            <div id="ajax"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

test2.php

```
<input id="button" type="button" value="Ajax" data-theme="b"/>
```

Comment: you need to add .trigger('create'); on the new elements so jQM can add the additional markup

Comment: I tried adding .trigger("create"); and it didn't help, maybe I entered it wrong.

Comment: after your ajax has loaded, you need to use the trigger.('create') on the page. So: $('#test').trigger.('create');

Comment: Magic, that did it i was not putting the create trigger on the page. THANKS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .trigger('create'); on the page like this:

```
 $('#test').trigger('create');
```

Comment: $('#test').trigger('create'); - you must have added the . by typing too fast :)